# E possivel fazer requisições em aplicativos android atraves da web com php?

Tags: php, android, apk

Estou trabalhando com php e inicialmente fiquei curioso com uma coisa, eu estou necessitando fazer uma requisição (particularmete um login) em um aplicativo android mais com minha plataforma em php na web, existe algum serviço que me permita emular um apk em um servidor e fazer requisições nele ?

Comment: Basta instalar BlueStacks(recomendo este) ou utilizar o Emulador do próprio AndroidStudio que está presente no AVD Manager que é um plugin do próprio AndroidStudio, assim você poderá rodar aplicativos android e fazer quaisquer requisições que você precisar nele.

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não é possível, isto porque você está trabalhando com um sistema completamente diferente de um sistema mobile.

O que você pode fazer é emular o android em uma aplicação no SO, dentro deste android você pode emular o aplicativo e ai sim você talvez consiga fazer com que outros sistemas possam interagir com ele através de scripts dentro do próprio emulador.

Mas emular um APK através da web não.

Comment: Estou triste porem sei que mais pra frente vamos ter esse integração  com certeza pois a nessecidade de se ter um serviço assim e grande

Comment: Eu não acho muito provável, são ecossistemas diferentes... Creio que a solução do emulador vai ser a mais permanente que teremos por muito tempo ainda